# How can I get table with dynamic data from a url using Selenium and xpath, or other alternative?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to retrieve the main "Network Status" table data from this site:

http://dev.cryptolions.io/mainnet/

I have tried many combinations of selenium functions populated with Chrome's copy selector and copy Xpath, but am not having any luck. The site opens with selenium, but I keep getting errors similar to this. What am I missing here?

Getting the table in any number of data structures would be ok. But a dictionary, JSON, or something I can load into a pandas df would be ideal.

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="bpTableSystem"]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.87)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.40.565498
>   (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17134 x86_64)

My Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe') 
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('http://dev.cryptolions.io/mainnet/')

time.sleep(30)
content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bpTableSystem"]')
print content.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined two Chrome instances: `browser` and `driver`. You navigate to target page with `browser` while trying to find `table` with `driver`.

Simply replace

```
browser.get('http://dev.cryptolions.io/mainnet/')
```

with

```
driver.get('http://dev.cryptolions.io/mainnet/')
```

Comment: Your comment solved my problem instantly. Many Thanks!